# custom password generator help needed

Tags: passwords, brute-force

I have an important encrypted file i created some time ago using [cryptainer](http://www.cypherix.com/cryptainerle/) but have forgotten the password to it. I know what set of words and numbers i used for it but unsure of the order they went in, for example:

> [my birth year][my girlfriends name][a ten digit number i know][my phone number][my house number][my daughters name][my daughters birth date]

obviously this is a very complex password but wanted to know if there is any program that can do me a list by swapping those around in all possible ways but not necessary always using all of those, as it might not have my house number in my password, it could possibly be just

> [ten digit number i know][my phone number][my girlfriends name]

and so on, so my password could be between 6 and 50 characters long.

I know I'm stupid for forgetting it but when something is fresh in you're mind at the time it seemed easy to remember but I haven't used it for some time.

I was given a link to a website showing a way this can be done in pseudo code but like i said i'm no programmer and wouldn't know where to start.

this is the link i was given http://permute.tchs.info/

I'm really confused with certain password crackers on the net and how to use my own sets of numbers and words. Would anyone know of any program that would generate all possible passwords using only my sets of numbers and words as i would really appreciate it.

As this would generate a very long list of all possible passwords it would be ideal to have a program to check them with my cryptainter file but I'm not sure if there is such a program.

Comment: You know that's `7!` or `5040` different possible combinations, right?

Comment: The possible permutations are 7! = 5040 possibilities. Not that hard to compile by hand. An advice: assign each of your values a number from 1 to 7, get a list of permutations of {1, 7} and start trying.

Comment: wow I didn't know that lol. to be honest if there isn't any program to check them for me i don't mind just running through the list over weeks by trying so many a day. Seems silly but it's either that or give up and i never like giving up :)

Comment: Actually, there are more than 5040 combinations. You're forgetting that they can also be empty. 7 * 6! ways to chose one empty position, 7*6 * 5! to chose two empty... The real number (I think) is 7*7! = 35280.

Comment: To get the list you can use [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html). Just choose: n=7, r=7, Order Important: yes, Repetition: no, choose `Joined`, put your values in the field below and click `List`

Comment: thanks for you're advice but like i said I'm not a programmer and don't understand how to do what you suggested.  If some kind person wrote the program and told me where to type in my sets of numbers and words then that would be great. I am a total beginner in programming and have only just started to read up on it but there is so many different languages it's hard to know where to start.  i have been told that Python is easy to get started with but I wouldn't know.

Comment: Thank you _mornaner_ for that link, it seems to do what i wanted but haven't had time to play around with it at the moment, I will give it another try later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this AutoITscript implementation from [Hananel Hazan website](http://hananel.hazan.org.il/2011/09/brute-force-truecrypt-password/) 
you can modify it to meet your terms.

---

```
dim $one, $two, $three, $four, $five, $six, $seven, $eight, $pw, $pp, $count, $truecryptPath, $containerPath
$truecryptPath = “C:\PROGRA~1\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe /q background /s “
$containerPath = “d:\cscs2.tre”
dim $numberOfCharacters = 92
dim $Array[$numberOfCharacters+1]
$Array[0]=”a”
$Array[1]=”b”
$Array[2]=”c”
$Array[3]=”d”
$Array[4]=”e”
$Array[5]=”f”
$Array[6]=”g”
$Array[7]=”h”
$Array[8]=”i”
$Array[9]=”j”
$Array[10]=”k”
$Array[11]=”l”
$Array[12]=”m”
$Array[13]=”n”
$Array[14]=”o”
$Array[15]=”p”
$Array[16]=”q”
$Array[17]=”r”
$Array[18]=”s”
$Array[19]=”t”
$Array[20]=”u”
$Array[21]=”v”
$Array[22]=”w”
$Array[23]=”x”
$Array[24]=”y”
$Array[25]=”z”
$Array[26]=”A”
$Array[27]=”B”
$Array[28]=”C”
$Array[29]=”D”
$Array[30]=”E”
$Array[31]=”F”
$Array[32]=”G”
$Array[33]=”H”
$Array[34]=”I”
$Array[35]=”J”
$Array[36]=”K”
$Array[37]=”L”
$Array[38]=”M”
$Array[39]=”N”
$Array[40]=”O”
$Array[41]=”P”
$Array[42]=”Q”
$Array[43]=”R”
$Array[44]=”S”
$Array[45]=”T”
$Array[46]=”U”
$Array[47]=”V”
$Array[48]=”W”
$Array[49]=”X”
$Array[50]=”Y”
$Array[51]=”Z”
$Array[52]=”!”
$Array[53]=”@”
$Array[54]=”#”
$Array[55]=”$”
$Array[56]=”%”
$Array[57]=”^”
$Array[58]=”&”
$Array[59]=”*”
$Array[60]=”(“
$Array[61]=”)”
$Array[62]=”_”
$Array[63]=”+”
$Array[64]=”~”
$Array[65]=”`”
$Array[66]=”1″
$Array[67]=”2″
$Array[68]=”3″
$Array[69]=”4″
$Array[70]=”5″
$Array[71]=”6″
$Array[72]=”7″
$Array[73]=”8″
$Array[74]=”9″
$Array[75]=”0″
$Array[76]=”-”
$Array[77]=”=”
$Array[78]=”["
$Array[79]=”]”
$Array[80]=”\”
$Array[81]=”{“
$Array[82]=”}”
$Array[83]=”|”
$Array[84]=”;”
$Array[85]=”:”
$Array[86]=”‘”
$Array[87]=”"”"
$Array[88]=”,”
$Array[89]=”.”
$Array[90]=”/”
$Array[91]=”?”

$count = 0
for $two = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $one = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
$pw = $Array[$one]
$pw &= $Array[$two]
$count = $count+1
$pp  = Run(@COMSPEC & ” /c ” & $truecryptPath & ” /p “& $pw & ” /e /m ro /m rm /v ” &$containerPath )
ProcessSetPriority($pp, 0)

if $count>25 then
While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend
EndIf

Next
Next

While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend

$count = 0
for $three = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $two = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $one = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
$pw = $Array[$one]
$pw &= $Array[$two]
$pw &= $Array[$three]
$count = $count+1
$pp  = Run(@COMSPEC & ” /c ” & $truecryptPath & ” /p “& $pw & ” /e /m ro /m rm /v ” &$containerPath )
ProcessSetPriority($pp, 0)

if $count>25 then
While ProcessExists($pp)>0
$count = 0
Wend
EndIf

Next
Next
Next

While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend

$count = 0
for $four = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $three = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $two = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $one = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
$pw = $Array[$one]
$pw &= $Array[$two]
$pw &= $Array[$three]
$pw &= $Array[$four]
$count = $count+1
$pp  = Run(@COMSPEC & ” /c ” & $truecryptPath & ” /p “& $pw & ” /e /m ro /m rm /v ” &$containerPath )
ProcessSetPriority($pp, 0)

if $count>25 then
While ProcessExists($pp)>0
$count = 0
Wend
EndIf

Next
Next
Next
Next

While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend

$count = 0
for $five = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $four = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $three = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $two = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $one = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
$pw = $Array[$one]
$pw &= $Array[$two]
$pw &= $Array[$three]
$pw &= $Array[$four]
$pw &= $Array[$five]
$count = $count+1
$pp  = Run(@COMSPEC & ” /c ” & $truecryptPath & ” /p “& $pw & ” /e /m ro /m rm /v ” &$containerPath )
ProcessSetPriority($pp, 0)

if $count>25 then
While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend
$count = 0
EndIf

Next
Next
Next
Next
Next

While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend

$count = 0
FOR $six = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $five = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $four = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $three = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $two = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $one = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
$pw = $Array[$one]
$pw &= $Array[$two]
$pw &= $Array[$three]
$pw &= $Array[$four]
$pw &= $Array[$five]
$pw &= $Array[$six]
$count = $count+1
$pp  = Run(@COMSPEC & ” /c ” & $truecryptPath & ” /p “& $pw & ” /e /m ro /m rm /v ” &$containerPath )
ProcessSetPriority($pp, 0)

if $count>25 then
While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend
$count = 0
EndIf

Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next

While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend

$count = 0
for $seven = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
FOR $six = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $five = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $four = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $three = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $two = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $one = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
$pw = $Array[$one]
$pw &= $Array[$two]
$pw &= $Array[$three]
$pw &= $Array[$four]
$pw &= $Array[$five]
$pw &= $Array[$six]
$pw &= $Array[$seven]
$count = $count+1
$pp  = Run(@COMSPEC & ” /c ” & $truecryptPath & ” /p “& $pw & ” /e /m ro /m rm /v ” &$containerPath )
ProcessSetPriority($pp, 0)

if $count>25 then
While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend
$count = 0
EndIf

Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next

While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend

for $eight = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $seven = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
FOR $six = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $five = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $four = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $three = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $two = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
for $one = 0 to $numberOfCharacters
$pw = $Array[$one]
$pw &= $Array[$two]
$pw &= $Array[$three]
$pw &= $Array[$four]
$pw &= $Array[$five]
$pw &= $Array[$six]
$pw &= $Array[$seven]
$pw &= $Array[$eight]
$count = $count+1
$pp  = Run(@COMSPEC & ” /c ” & $truecryptPath & ” /p “& $pw & ” /e /m ro /m rm /v ” &$containerPath )
ProcessSetPriority($pp, 0)

if $count>25 then
While ProcessExists($pp)>0
Wend
$count = 0
EndIf

Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
Next
```